# Hot to stop Shotwell wallpaper slideshow

Tags: gnome, desktop-background, shotwell

I used shotwell to create a wallpaper slideshow. Since then I am experiencing a massive memory leakage of gnome-shell and I want to turn it off again.

**How can I do that?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the wallpaper from **System Setings**, it will automatically stop.